# Combine multiple Rows with same ID and sum up values

Tags: pandas

I'm preparing the migration of a user list and struggle with the following last task:

### The problem

- I have a list of entries with users and their subscriptions.
- Each row is one subscription.
- Each row also contains all user information like email adress and name.
- Some users have multiple subscriptions.
- All subscriptions have various and different amounts of cost and startdates.

This is the initial situation:

[image: Initial Situation]

### The goal

After the merge, we plan to have only one subscription per user. The merge should do the following:

1. Find all users who have multiple subscriptions, the email adress as the unique identifier
2. Sum up the total value of all subscription cost from the user
3. Add the correct subscription name (Beginner if subscription < 20$, Pro if subscription > 20$
4. Find the start date of the youngest subscriptions and add this to the row
5. At the end, there should be only one row with all information from
   the user and his subscription (with total sum and latest date) and all other rows from that user should be deleted.

This is the targeted output:

[image: Target Situation]

Answer (score 2):

Yet another classical example of `groupby`+`agg`:

```
df['SubscriptionName'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SubscriptionName'])
df2 = df.groupby(['Email']).agg({'Username': 'last',
                                 'SubscriptionDate': 'max',
                                 'Sum': 'sum',
                                 })
df2['SubscriptionName'] = df2['Sum'].gt(20).map({True: 'Pro', False: 'Beginner'})
```

*NB. not providing an example output as OP had no provided dataset as text*

Comment: That works fine. But when I output the dataframe, it only contains the columns defined in `agg` - Is there a way to include all other not mentioned columns? (in the original data, there are more columns than the ones mentioned in the OP)